# Compress and Encrypt vs. Decrypt and Decompress

Tags: c#, .net

take a look at this to methods:

```
public void CompressAndEncrypt(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    Aes aes = Aes.Create();

    aes.Key = Key;
    aes.IV = IV;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    aes.BlockSize = 128;

    ICryptoTransform aesEncryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor();

    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new(output, aesEncryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    using (GZipStream compressedStream = new(cryptoStream, CompressionLevel.SmallestSize))
    {
        input.CopyTo(compressedStream);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    }
}
```

and

```
public void DecryptAndDecompress(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    Aes aes = Aes.Create();

    aes.Key = Key;
    aes.IV = IV;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    aes.BlockSize = 128;

    ICryptoTransform aesDecryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor();

    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new(input, aesDecryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    using (GZipStream decompressedStream = new(cryptoStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        decompressedStream.CopyTo(output);
    }
}
```

The input and output Stream can be considered as FileStream. As you can see, the first method compresses and encrypt a Stream, while the second method decrypts and decompress a Stream.

The first method works fine, but if a take the result of the first method and pass it to the second, .NET says:

> System.IO.InvalidDataException. "The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method."

Any suggestion?

Comment: You should reverse the order of one of them. Either encrypt, compress and decompress, decrypt or compress, encrypt and decrypt, decompress.

Comment: Are you sure you reset the position of the stream?

Comment: @Silvermind I would recommend against encrypting before compressing... You can't compress encrypted data.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Logical, but you mean that it is futile instead of can't, right? Because it is hard to optimize a stream of 'low repeating' bytes.

Comment: I mean that you actually can't - You can try, but the data size will not decrease (and it's likely to actually increase instead, because of the compression header etc). Most encrypted data appears to be random, and random data is not compressible.

Comment: @MatthewWatson that's something only the Mr Punchards that struggled with PKZIP and ARJ would remember :P

Comment: @MatthewWatson I was thinking inside the context of code execution. I get your point, but we mean the same thing. You can execute the function to compress, but it will probably not be smaller. In terms of can't I referred to 'throws an exception'.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is with `cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();` before disposing/flushing the compression stream. This slightly altered example works for me:

```
[Test]
public void EncryptDecrypt()
{
    var source = new MemoryStream();
    var data = new byte[] {42, 3, 5, 100, 255, 100, 255, 100, 255, 100, 255, 100, 255, 100, 255, 100, 255};
    source.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    source.Position = 0;

    var encrypted = new MemoryStream();
    var (key, iv) = CompressAndEncrypt(source, encrypted);

    var result = new MemoryStream();
    encrypted.Position = 0;
    DecryptAndDecompress(encrypted, result, key, iv);

    result.Position = 0;
    var resultData = new byte[data.Length];
    result.Read(resultData, 0, resultData.Length);

    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(data, resultData);

}

public (byte[] key, byte[] Iv) CompressAndEncrypt(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    Aes aes = Aes.Create("AesManaged");

    aes.GenerateIV();
    aes.GenerateKey();
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    aes.BlockSize = 128;

    ICryptoTransform aesEncryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor();

    using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new(output, aesEncryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write, true);
    using GZipStream compressedStream = new(cryptoStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal, true);
    input.CopyTo(compressedStream);

    return (aes.Key, aes.IV);
}

public void DecryptAndDecompress(Stream input, Stream output, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
{
    Aes aes = Aes.Create("AesManaged");

    aes.Key = key;
    aes.IV = iv;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    aes.BlockSize = 128;

    ICryptoTransform aesDecryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor();

    using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new(input, aesDecryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read, true);
    using GZipStream decompressedStream = new(cryptoStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true);
    decompressedStream.CopyTo(output);
}
```

Comment: Oops, I got confused